# Problems using OneHotEncoder from sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am attempting to one-hot encode some text, character by character. I have mapped the text to integer values first.

```
with open('data/texts/anna.txt') as data:
    text = data.read()

vocab    = tuple(set(text))
int2char = dict(enumerate(vocab))
char2int = {i: char for char, i in int2char.items()}

encoded    = np.array([char2int[i] for i in text]).reshape(1, -1)
categories = np.array([char2int[i] for i in vocab])

# encoder = OneHotEncoder(categories) 
encoder = OneHotEncoder()
encoder.fit(encoded)

test = encoder.transform(encoded[:10])
```

Two things:

1. This operation is incredibly slow on both the fit and the transform, so I must be doing something wrong.
2. The test outcome is a (1, 1985223) ndarray of all ones. I expected only the 10 values I passed it to be encoded. So again, I'm doing something wrong.

Maybe I should be treating my text as 1985223 samples instead of features? **Edit:** This seems to be the case. Now I'm just wondering about the intuition behind this.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `CountVectorizer` instead as it is specifically design to one hot encode vocabulary

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

sample = 'this is a sample'

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
vectorizer.fit(sample.split())

print(vectorizer.transform(['this']).toarray())
```

Comment: Oh, that's very cool! Good to know! However, I still do have the question about the intuition behind whether or not a character in a sentence should be considered a variable or a sample? I'm learning about RNN's and so my question is more conceptual than technical.